# Delegating responsibilities to WinForm controls -- should controls be aware of each other's actions?

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I have a handful of controls on a form:

- A check box which is responsible for enabling/disabling all other controls on the page based on its checked state.
- A few radio buttons which are responsible for enabling/disabling specific controls on  the page based on their checked states.
- Other controls which are manipulated by the above controls.

A few scenarios arise:

- When the form initializes, I load the checkbox's state. Then, it enables or disables the rest of the controls on the form.
- As the form continues initializing, I load the state of the radio buttons. This has the chance of undoing the previous requirement if a radio button is checked but disabled. As such,  I check to make sure the radio button is enabled first.
- After the form has loaded the user can check or uncheck radio buttons. This is a trivial case, I just run the code which fulfilled the last requirement. Another case, though, is that the user may check/uncheck the checkbox. When the checkbox becomes enabled it wants to re-enable all controls on the page because it disabled them. Doing so will break the radio button's requirements, though.

This scenario is pretty trivial to handle with brute force. I've created a couple of methods to highlight:

```
private void ChkBxSnmPv3OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    snmpSettingsErrorProvider.Clear();

    foreach (Control control in grpBxSNMPv3.Controls)
    {
        if (control != sender)
            control.Enabled = ((CheckBox)sender).Checked;
    }
}

private void rdBtnAuthNoPriv_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton authNoPrivRadioButton = ((RadioButton)sender);

    if (authNoPrivRadioButton.Enabled)
    {
        bool isChecked = authNoPrivRadioButton.Checked;

        SetControlState(cmbBxAuthProtocol, isChecked);
        SetControlState(mskdTxtBxAuthPassword, isChecked);
        SetControlState(mskdTxtBxAuthPasswordConfirm, isChecked);

        SetControlState(cmbBxPrivacyProtocol, !isChecked);
        SetControlState(mskdTxtBxPrivacyPassword, !isChecked);
        SetControlState(mskdTxtBxPrivacyPasswordConfirm, !isChecked);
    }
}
//More methods for other checkedChange and also for when rdBtn's enable.
```

Rough idea of layout:

[image]

With all that said, my question is 'simple':

- Methods should work without the assumption that other methods exist. Yet, if I keep rdBtn's logic nieve of chkBx's existence then I will have code which has to fight each other.

I could write my code like this:

```
private void ChkBxSnmPv3OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    snmpSettingsErrorProvider.Clear();

    txtBxEngineID = ((CheckBox)sender).Checked;
    rdBtnAuthNoPriv = ((CheckBox)sender).Checked;
    rdBtnAuthPriv = ((CheckBox)sender).Checked;
    rdBtnNoAuthNoPriv = ((CheckBox)sender).Checked;

    //Pass work for enabling Auth and Priv fields to rdBtn events.
}
```

This solution is more efficient and guarantees I won't see any flickering. Yet, it also means that for a 'successful completion' of enabling all controls on the page my chkBx now has to rely on the rdBtn's logic. Is this good programming practice?

Comment: The question doesn't make a lot of sense, these are already snippets of code that exist in the *form*.  Or UserControl, can't tell.  Not code that's inside the control class.  Which is what events are all about, letting some kind of *other* code know that something interesting happened.  This code very much belongs in the form, the only class that knows anything about the collection of controls it hosts.

Comment: Hey, sorry. I agree -- my initial post does not make enough sense. I will edit it today when I have a bit of time to make it more understandable for legacy purposes. I am confused by your second point, though. Should events never be used if a single class is involved, then? Do you have reading for me to back that up? The code is on a user control which is loaded onto a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up going with. I'm pretty OK with it aside from the two list's I'm initializing. They should probably be in their own controls, but I can't bring myself to do it quite yet.

```
public partial class DeviceSnmpSettings : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly List<Control> AuthenticationControls = new List<Control>(6);
    private readonly List<Control> PrivacyControls = new List<Control>(6);
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public DeviceSnmpSettings()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeAuthControls();
        InitializePrivacyControls();
    }

    public DeviceSnmpSettings(Point location)
        : this()
    {
        Location = location;
    }

    //TODO: Move out into sub-user control?
    private void InitializeAuthControls()
    {
        AuthenticationControls.Add(lblAuthPassword);
        AuthenticationControls.Add(mskdTxtBxAuthPassword);
        AuthenticationControls.Add(lblAuthProtocol);
        AuthenticationControls.Add(cmbBxAuthProtocol);
        AuthenticationControls.Add(lblAuthPasswordConfirm);
        AuthenticationControls.Add(mskdTxtBxAuthPasswordConfirm);
    }
    //TODO: Move out into sub-user control?
    private void InitializePrivacyControls()
    {
        PrivacyControls.Add(lblPrivacyPassword);
        PrivacyControls.Add(mskdTxtBxPrivacyPassword);
        PrivacyControls.Add(lblPrivacyProtocol);
        PrivacyControls.Add(cmbBxPrivacyProtocol);
        PrivacyControls.Add(lblPrivacyPasswordConfirm);
        PrivacyControls.Add(mskdTxtBxPrivacyPasswordConfirm);
    }

    private bool SNMPv3Enabled
    {
        get { return chkBxSNMPv3.Checked; }
        set { chkBxSNMPv3.Checked = value; }
    }

    private SNMPV3Mode SecurityMode
    {
        get
        {
            SNMPV3Mode mode = SNMPV3Mode.NoAuthNoPriv;

            if (rdBtnAuthNoPriv.Checked)
                mode = SNMPV3Mode.AuthNoPriv;
            else if(rdBtnAuthPriv.Checked)
                mode = SNMPV3Mode.AuthPriv;

            return mode;
        }
        set
        {
            switch (value)
            {
                case SNMPV3Mode.NoAuthNoPriv:
                    rdBtnNoAuthNoPriv.Checked = true;
                    break;
                case SNMPV3Mode.AuthNoPriv:
                    rdBtnAuthNoPriv.Checked = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    rdBtnAuthPriv.Checked = true;
                    break;
            }

            OnSecurityModeChanged();
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnSecurityModeChanged()
    {
        AuthenticationControls.ForEach(control => SetControlEnabledState(control, AuthenticationEnabled));
        PrivacyControls.ForEach(control => SetControlEnabledState(control, PrivacyEnabled));
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SecurityMode");
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }

    private bool AuthenticationEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            return SNMPv3Enabled && (SecurityMode == SNMPV3Mode.AuthPriv || SecurityMode == SNMPV3Mode.AuthNoPriv);
        }
    }

    private bool PrivacyEnabled
    {
        get { return SNMPv3Enabled && SecurityMode == SNMPV3Mode.AuthPriv; }
    }

    private void ChkBxSnmPv3OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        SetControlEnabledStates();
    }

    private void SetControlEnabledStates()
    {
        snmpSettingsErrorProvider.Clear();

        foreach (Control control in grpBxSNMPv3.Controls)
        {
            //Check each of the lists for the control to prevent flickering.
            if (control != chkBxSNMPv3 && !AuthenticationControls.Contains(control) && !PrivacyControls.Contains(control))
                control.Enabled = SNMPv3Enabled;
        }

        //Need to validate that our radio button's checked state is reflected properly.
        AuthenticationControls.ForEach(control => SetControlEnabledState(control, AuthenticationEnabled));
        PrivacyControls.ForEach(control => SetControlEnabledState(control, PrivacyEnabled));
    }

    public void LoadFields(NetworkDiscovery networkDiscovery)
    {
        SNMPv3Enabled = networkDiscovery.Snmpv3Enabled;
        SecurityMode = networkDiscovery.SecurityMode;
        txtBxSNMPv3Username.Text = networkDiscovery.Username;
        mskdTxtBxAuthPassword.Text = networkDiscovery.AuthPassword;
        mskdTxtBxAuthPasswordConfirm.Text = networkDiscovery.AuthPassword;
        cmbBxAuthProtocol.SelectedItem = networkDiscovery.AuthProtocol.ToString();
        mskdTxtBxPrivacyPassword.Text = networkDiscovery.PrivacyPassword;
        mskdTxtBxPrivacyPasswordConfirm.Text = networkDiscovery.PrivacyPassword;
        cmbBxPrivacyProtocol.SelectedItem = networkDiscovery.PrivacyProtocol.ToString();

        SetControlEnabledStates();
    }

    private void SetControlEnabledState(Control control, bool enabled)
    {
        control.Enabled = enabled;
                    //Clear errors set on errorProvider when control is disabled.
        if (!control.Enabled)
            snmpSettingsErrorProvider.SetError(control, string.Empty);
    }

    private void rdBtnNoAuthNoPriv_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (((RadioButton)sender).Checked)
            SecurityMode = SNMPV3Mode.NoAuthNoPriv;
    }

    private void rdBtnAuthNoPriv_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (((RadioButton)sender).Checked)
            SecurityMode = SNMPV3Mode.AuthNoPriv;
    }

    private void rdBtnAuthPriv_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (((RadioButton)sender).Checked)
            SecurityMode = SNMPV3Mode.AuthPriv;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is sensible code to keep in the form, however I'd make a few suggestions;

1) Casting has a minor processing cost so you should avoid casting inside a loop. In fact, as a general concept, you should avoid performing any repeated action inside a loop when the outcome is guaranteed to remain the same. So you could improve your first method like so;

```
private void ChkBxSnmPv3OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    snmpSettingsErrorProvider.Clear();

    // cast the sender once only
    CheckBox cb = sender as CheckBox;
    if (null == cb) return;

    foreach (Control control in grpBxSNMPv3.Controls)
    {
        if (control != sender)
            control.Enabled = cb.Checked;
    }
}
```

2) I'd suggest moving out the enabling/disabling logic into a separate method, and then calling it from your control event handlers. This will enable you to reuse the same logic should you decide to, from some other control. Tightly coupling behaviours to control events, I find leads to duplicated code. Like so;

```
private void ChkBxSnmPv3OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    snmpSettingsErrorProvider.Clear();

    // cast the sender once only
    CheckBox cb = sender as CheckBox;
    if (null == cb) return;

    SetEnabled(grpBxSNMPv3, cb.Checked, new[] { cb });
}

private void SetEnabled(Control parent, bool isEnabled, Control[] exludeControls)
{
    if (null == parent) return;

    foreach (Control control in parent.Controls)
    {
        if (!excludeControls.Contains(control))
            control.Enabled = isEnabled;
    }
}
```

You've now got a reusable method to enable/disable all controls contained by another.

3) Regarding your final question, yes I think this approach is fine. Less coupling is always a good thing. Think about how to design your methods to be more reusable, and I think you'll come up with a clean solution.

Comment: +1 for the suggestions. I did in fact end up following all of these suggestions before updating my thread -- so great minds think alike. I went ahead and posted a clean solution for future people. Let me know if you see anything poor about it. :)